# np.roll vs scipy.interpolation.shift--discrepancy for integer shift values

Tags: python, numpy, ndimage

I wrote some code to shift an array, and was trying to generalize it to handle non-integer shifts using the "shift" function in `scipy.ndimage`.  The data is circular and so the result should wrap around, exactly as the `np.roll` command does it.

However, `scipy.ndimage.shift` does not appear to wrap integer shifts properly.  The following code snippet shows the discrepancy:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as sciim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def shiftfunc(data, amt):
    return sciim.interpolation.shift(data, amt, mode='wrap', order = 3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xvals = np.arange(100)*1.0

    yvals = np.sin(xvals*0.1)

    rollshift   = np.roll(yvals, 2)

    interpshift = shiftfunc(yvals, 2)

    plt.plot(xvals, rollshift, label = 'np.roll', alpha = 0.5)
    plt.plot(xvals, interpshift, label = 'interpolation.shift', alpha = 0.5)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image: roll vs shift]

It can be seen that the first couple of values are highly discrepant, while the rest are fine.  I suspect this is an implementation error of the prefiltering and interpolation operation when using the `wrap` option.  A way around this would be to modify `shiftfunc` to revert to np.roll when the shift value is an integer, but this is unsatisfying.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Is there a way to make `ndimage.shift` coincide with `np.roll`?

Comment: [`ndimage.shift`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift.html#scipy-ndimage-interpolation-shift) is an interpolation-based routine while `roll` just moves elements around. So there obviously will be dicrepancies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is anything wrong with the shift function. when you use roll, your need to chop an extra element for fair comparision. please see the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as sciim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


def shiftfunc(data, amt):
    return sciim.interpolation.shift(data, amt, mode='wrap', order = 3)

def rollfunc(data,amt):
    rollshift   = np.roll(yvals, amt)
    # Here I remove one element (first one before rollshift) from the array 
    return np.concatenate((rollshift[:amt], rollshift[amt+1:]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shift_by = 5
    xvals = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20)
    yvals = np.sin(xvals)
    rollshift   = rollfunc(yvals, shift_by)
    interpshift = shiftfunc(yvals,shift_by)
    plt.plot(xvals, yvals, label = 'original', alpha = 0.5)
    plt.plot(xvals[1:], rollshift, label = 'np.roll', alpha = 0.5,marker='s')
    plt.plot(xvals, interpshift, label = 'interpolation.shift', alpha = 0.5,marker='o') 
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  I was assuming "roll" worked differently than it did.  good find.